# when i am trying to call a servlet page from my jsp page using anchor tag it showing an error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a simple jsp page with one anchor tag which will call the servlet page:
The following is the jsp code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Download Data</title>
</head>
<body>
View data in following format:<br>

<a href = "Filedownload">MS-Excel</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet page :

```
package com.primeki.devlopment.usm.view;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ExcelServlet")
public class Filedownload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Filedownload() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Name\tJob\tSalary");
        out.println("Raj\tAccountant\t20000");
        out.println("Vinay\tAccountant\t20000");
        out.println("Rajesh\tAccountant\t20000");
        out.println("\tTotal:\t=sum(c2:c3)");
        out.close();
    }

}
```

I am getting an error when i am clicking the anchor tag ...
i want to make an excel sheet to get download by click on the anchor tag .. but i am getting an error ... plz help in this....

Comment: Soooooo... What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be mistaken because I am new in Java EE but it seems that `<a href = "Filedownload">MS-Excel</a>` anchor is redirecting to `Filedownload` while your servlet is `@WebServlet("/ExcelServlet")`.
Try changing your anchor to `<a href = "ExcelServlet">MS-Excel</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You have named your `WebServlet "/ExcelServlet"` which means that it weill respond on requests made to http://{server}/{app-name}/ExcelServlet and you have a link with  `href = "Filedownload"`